# Mysql get max value in several ranges

Tags: mysql

This question is regarding mysql. I want to get the maximum value in several groups of min and max values. There is no group column defined, the "groups" are based on ranges that I define. I think this is explained better with an example. What I want is the following set of queries into a single one:

```
select max(value) from tablename where value between 5000 and 5499;
select max(value) from tablename where value between 7500 and 7999;
select max(value) from tablename where value between 7000 and 7499;
select max(value) from tablename where value between 6500 and 6999;
select max(value) from tablename where value between 6000 and 6499;
select max(value) from tablename where value between 5500 and 5999;
select max(value) from tablename where value between 8001 and 8998;
```

So I can get a list of the max value on each range. I did not found anything similar in any question.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is to use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  range1, range2, max(value)
FROM
  (SELECT 5000 AS range1, 5499 AS range2
   UNION ALL SELECT 7500, 7999
   UNION ALL SELECT 7000, 7499
   UNION ALL SELECT 6500, 6999
   UNION ALL SELECT 6000, 6499
   UNION ALL SELECT 5500, 5999
   UNION ALL SELECT 8001, 8998
  ) AS ranges
  LEFT JOIN tablename ON value BETWEEN range1 AND range2
GROUP BY
  range1, range2
```

of course if ranges are like the ones given you can calculate ranges with a formula, but here you are free to define any range you want. You might also prefer to use a "ranges" table, with proper indexes, to have better performances.

Comment: Hello, I think your solution is the one that better fits my case. But I'm only getting ONE result, while I expected one result per range. If I execute only the select union part it works, returns all ranges, but it does not work in conjunction.

Comment: @Danielo515 sorry i forgot a GROUP BY ... please see my updated answer, should be fine now

Comment: Now it works perfectly! Thank you very much. It was definitively far away from my current MySQL skills. Now I have to take some time to understood it. Many regards

Answer (score 4):

Try with:

```
  SELECT MAX(value)
    FROM tablename
   WHERE value BETWEEN 5000 AND 8998
GROUP BY FLOOR(value / 500)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dbff2/2)

Comment: Since this solution is elegant, it relies on the fact that the ranges are spaced by a fixed value. Useful but not for my case. Thanks

Comment: @Danielo515 You can use it for the equal ranges and make union with non-standard ranges.

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(case when value between 5000 and 5499 then value else 0 end) as max_5000_5499,
       max(case when value between 7500 and 7999 then value else 0 end) as max_7500_7999
from tablename
```