# How to get a maximum value of a column for several ranges of values of another column, in a single query, with SQLAlchemy ORM?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, orm

I have a MySQL database table with a date-time column and a associated data column. I need maximum values of the data column for multiple pre-defined date-time ranges. Let's say I have a row for every 5 minutes and I need the maximum value of the data column for every consecutive 12-hour ranges. I need to do it in one query and I need it done with SQLAlchemy's ORM functions.

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30888856/13602317) which does what I need. However, I struggled to implement it using SQLAlchemy's ORM approach. Specifically, the parentheses with the subquery using union_all is where my understanding of SQLAlchemy is lacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think maybe you need to apply `subquery()` but maybe include the code you have tried.  Here is a version that seems to work but I don't know a lot about datetime handling in `mysql` and datetime handling can get really complicated so better research that separately.  This is using `"core"` and the `"ORM"` layers together in SQLAlchemy 2+ by utilizing `select()`.

I try to rollback the transaction in this example so I can run the example over and over again.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import (
    Integer,
    String,
    DateTime,
    ForeignKey,
    UniqueConstraint,
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import (
    Column,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import backref, relationship, declarative_base, Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, union_all, literal_column, func, and_, bindparam

engine = create_engine(f'mysql+pymysql://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASS}@{DB_IP}:{DB_PORT}', echo=True)

Base = declarative_base(metadata=MetaData(schema="testdb"))

from sqlalchemy import Column, String, SMALLINT, column
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import SMALLINT, TINYINT, BIGINT, CHAR

class Sample(Base):
    __tablename__ = "samples"
    id = Column(BIGINT(20), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    recorded_on = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    recorded_value = Column(BIGINT(20), nullable=False)


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


# Ranges are from the bottom of the hour ie. minute=0, second=0 to the bottom
# of the next hour so we can do >= range1 and < range2.
# We have to do the final hour with range2 as the next day.
RECORDED_ON_RANGES = [
    (datetime(year=2023, month=10, day=11, hour=hour, minute=0, second=0), datetime(year=2023, month=10, day=11, hour=hour+1, minute=0, second=0)) for hour in range(23)
] + [
    (datetime(year=2023, month=10, day=11, hour=23, minute=0, second=0), datetime(year=2023, month=10, day=12, hour=0, minute=0, second=0))
]


def get_test_recorded_value(hour, minute):
    # Try to include a few high and low in specific hours and then a fallback.
    if hour == 12 and minute % 2 == 0:
        return 100
    elif hour in (6, 12):
        return 3
    elif hour == 13 and minute % 3 == 0:
        return 4
    else:
        return 1

def get_test_samples():
    # Make samples every minute for hours 0 to 19 leave hours 20 to 23 empty to test LEFT OUTER JOIN.
    return (Sample(
                recorded_on=datetime(year=2023, month=10, day=11, hour=hour, minute=minute, second=0),
                recorded_value=get_test_recorded_value(hour, minute)) for minute in range(60) for hour in range(20))


with Session(engine) as session, session.begin():

    session.add_all(get_test_samples())

    session.flush()

    # Apply subquery() to allow subsequent reference to columns in union.
    # Only label the first select columns like the example.
    range_union = select(
        bindparam(None, value=RECORDED_ON_RANGES[0][0], type_=DateTime).label("range1"),
        bindparam(None, value=RECORDED_ON_RANGES[0][1], type_=DateTime).label("range2")
    ).union_all(*[
        select(
            bindparam(None, value=range1, type_=DateTime),
            bindparam(None, value=range2, type_=DateTime)
        ) for range1, range2 in RECORDED_ON_RANGES[1:]
    ]).subquery()

    q = select(
        range_union.c.range1,
        range_union.c.range2,
        func.max(Sample.recorded_value),
    ).outerjoin(
        Sample,
        and_(Sample.recorded_on >= range_union.c.range1, Sample.recorded_on < range_union.c.range2)
    ).group_by(range_union.c.range1, range_union.c.range2)

    for (range1, range2, max_value) in session.execute(q):
        print (range1, range2, max_value)

    session.rollback()
```

Comment: I finally got around to implementing it and it worked perfectly. I ended up not using it, because it was extremely slow and I had to find a different approach, but I learned a lot from your answer. Thanks!